# When is it profitable for a miner to mine non-empty blocks?

Tags: mining

Can someone explain the miner optimization calculus that relates block processing time, gas price, and uncle rate - when is it profitable for a miner to mine non-empty blocks?

This question was asked at https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/58smlm/can_someone_explain_the_miner_optimization/ it did not receive an answer and I'd love to know.

Comment: check this link http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9743/what-defines-the-reward-a-miner-gets-when-it-mines-an-empty-block-when-there-are