# What defines the reward a miner gets when it mines an empty block when there are no transactions?

Tags: mining

When no transactions are submitted to the network, miner can mine empty blocks and generate ether as rewards.

What defines the amount of ether a miner gets rewarded when it mines an empty block?

If the miner itself decides the amount, what prevents a miner from getting very high rewards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1-** Miners ming blocks and get rewarded as follow :

`n=5ETH static block reward`;

> A block on the main chain gets a reward of n. When a block includes an
>   uncle, the uncle gets a reward of 7/8*n (4.375 Ether) and the block including the
>   uncle gets a reward of 1/16*n (max 1/32*n, a maximum of 2 Uncles allowed per block). The miner will also receive all the gas in fees that it generates from the transactions in the block that it verifies

read about : [GHOST protocol](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~avivz/pubs/13/btc_scalability_full.pdf)

**2-** who set this reward is the Ethereum protocol for economic reasons it is currently equal to 5ETH for main blocks.

**3-** the miners however decides the **gasprice** which determines the fee that they will get if they include transactions into their blocks. they can't set a high gas price because there is a competition between them.

Read also : https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/31/uncle-rate-transaction-fee-analysis/

Answer (score 1):

The amount of Ether awarded for mining a block is a constant value defined by the protocol. Currently it's 5 ETH / Block. Additionally, the miner gets all the fees of transactions which are included in the block.